No capabilty when reflecting class with generic type
My objective in here was get the Type of the generic type passed on the class GenericTypeDummy. But somehow I can't achieved that because I keep getting error.
reflector.dart
import 'package:reflectable/reflectable.dart';

class Reflector extends Reflectable {
  const Reflector()
      : super(
          typeCapability,
          typeRelationsCapability,
          invokingCapability,
          newInstanceCapability,
          metadataCapability,
          declarationsCapability,
          reflectedTypeCapability,
          superclassQuantifyCapability,
          subtypeQuantifyCapability,
          instanceInvokeCapability,
        );
}

const reflector = Reflector();

this is my GenericTypeDummy class
@reflector
class GenericTypeDummy<T> {}

main.dart
Type getGenericType<T>() {
  var mirror = reflector.reflectType(GenericTypeDummy<T>) as ClassMirror;
  var typeArguments = mirror.typeArguments;
  if (typeArguments.isNotEmpty) {
    return typeArguments.first.reflectedType;
  }
  return dynamic;
}

print(getGenericType<List<int>>);

The error
Another exception was thrown: Reflecting on type 'GenericTypeDummy<List<int>>' without capability
